# Dynamic Header for angular app based on user type

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, angular-services

So I am creating a SPA on angular and i have to change the header based on the user. I created an archiecture component which has the header and footer and i have set it to the app component with the selector so that it is the starting point. So on start architecture component (header footer only) will check with ngOnInIt if user has logged in and if not navigate to login if user is logged in navigate to Home. I have set ngIf on header <li> to show if student, lecturer or staff is logged in.
But the problem is i cant reload on other pages or it will route to either login page or home page after checking if user is logged in cause the architecture (header footer ) component is used as the starting point and called from app component with selector. Furthermore i have to call

```
reloadPage(): void {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

to load the header based on the user after logging in and before navigating to home page.

I have found some content on ng-template and using observables to deal with this but im kind of confused on it . I hope someone can help me on this problem. As im new to angular and server side programming what i say and have used might be incorrect and confusing so if theres any advices on routing, services , subscribing etc ill be really thankful!!

EDIT ............................................................................

Alright So the project i am creating is an online learning platform for a institution so in app component i have given the router outlet. What i want is on loading the site to route to login if user is not logged in and is not contained within the storageService i created and used to check if userLoggedIn on ngOnInIt so then after validating login i want to navigate to architecture and then to home page with the architecture component displaying only the required header items for the logged in user type . Im struggling on coming up with the right logic to achieve this)))

Comment: I think your problem is to understand how angular works! First: window.location.reload() is absolutely wrong! Let Angular do refreshing the components. Second. Use a Subscription in a Service. If you change it "all" your components they bind to this will change if needed. Show a Stackblitz example or search for this things I wrote. You will find many posts and docs!

Comment: @Flo Thank you for the response im actually using a service to set user on login and get user again to check the user type. And i have kind of changed the Code again ill edit it above now can u give me some login on how i can arrange my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple example:

Build a `UserService`:

```js
export interface User {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
}

export class UserService {
  private currentUserSubject: Subject<User> = new Subject<User>();

  getCurrentUserSub() {
    return this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  login() { // Here we fake a login for this example
    const loggedInUser = { name: "Testuser", passwort: "Secret", role: "SuperAdmin" };

    this.currentUserSubject.next(loggedInUser); // Set the user
  }
}
```

**Now the `HeaderComponent` (or any other)**

```js
...
export class HeaderComponent implements onInit, onDestroy {
  currentUser!: User;
  userSub!: Subscription;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.userService.getCurrentUserSub().subscribe(data => {
      this.currentUser = data; // Every time the user changed in the Service, we get info
    });
  }

  ngOnDestory(): void {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe(); // Important!
  }
}
```

**Headers HTML**

```html
<div *ngIf="currentUser">
  Hello {{ currentUser.name }}! Your role is <b>{{ currentUser.role }}</b>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!currentUser">
  Nobody is logged in.
</div>
```

Now in **all** other `Components` you can (if needed) bind the user in the same way like in `HeaderComponent`.

In `LoginComponent` we now call the login method:

```
...
  login() {
    this.userService.login();
  }
...
```

So all components they subsribed to the `LoginService` `currentUserSubject` (getCurrentUserSub() - use always a `Observable` ***never*** directly a `Subject`) get the newest data automatically.

In `ngOnDestroy` we **unsubscribe**. If the component will destroyed we don't wanna updates any more (Memory Leaks or multiple subscritpion calls).

A **very much bigger** Project with this schema is here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-login?file=src/app/login/login.component.ts). But the principle is the same - is always the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot i believe this will work will try this now! BTW i just went through the stackblitz project and the authentication service was very similar to my storageService where i saved user on login and checked user in other components the difference was i did my checking in ngOnInIt where as the example had a guard that did the logic. Since my one was on ngOnInIt it would always route back to either login or home on reload on any page. But after seeing the guard i understood that the guard only works on specified routes and will be much more useful as we dont have to route all the time.

Comment: I have posted another question on interceptors after seeing your example can you review it and give me some feedback if possible.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249094/jwt-authentication-http-interceptor-in-angular)